# TestObserver not getting data in Unit Test

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have written unit test for below class. The TestObserver in the test is not able to receive any data. I'm clueless as to what needs to be done.

```
public class DataLocationMonitor {

    private PublishSubject<Object> dataLocatorSubject;


    public DataLocationMonitor(...) {
        this.dataLocatorSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    }


    public Observable<Object> getObservable() {
        return this.dataLocatorSubject;
    }


    public void handleData(Object data) {
        if (data instanceof DataMessage) {
            DataMessage message = new DataMessage(...);
            this.dataLocatorSubject.onNext(message);
        }   
    }  
}


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DataLocationMonitorTest {

private DataLocationMonitor target;

@Before
public void setUp() {   
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.target = new DataLocationMonitor(...);
}

 @Test
 public void handleData_dataLocatorSubjectOnNextCalled() {

    TestObserver<Object> observer= TestObserver.create(); 
    Observable<Object> dataLocatorSubject = this.target.getObservable();
    DataMessage data = new DataMessage();
    this.target.handleData(data);
    dataLocatorSubject.subscribe(observer);
    observer.assertSubscribed();
    observer.awaitCount(1);
    observer.assertValueCount(1);
 }
}
```

When I run the test I get java.lang.AssertionError: Value counts differ; Expected: 1, Actual: 0 (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0, timeout!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Swap the order of `this.target.handleData` and `dataLocatorSubject.subscribe` lines. `PublishSubject` doesn't retain items passing through so a late subscriber won't see any previously `onNext`'d items.

```java
TestObserver<Object> observer= TestObserver.create(); 
Observable<Object> dataLocatorSubject = this.target.getObservable();
DataMessage data = new DataMessage();

// subscribe first
dataLocatorSubject.subscribe(observer);
// signal next
this.target.handleData(data);

observer.assertSubscribed();
observer.awaitCount(1);
observer.assertValueCount(1);
```